# Call jQuery plugin on reload

Tags: jquery

I have come across a jQuery plugin that displays a "Loading" icon when a link is clicked on a page and the content is still loading. Here's how it is called:

```
$(".preloader").click(function(){ $.loader({ className:"ajLoad", content:"" }); });
```

Is there a way to modify this call to trigger it when the page is loaded the first time or re-loaded, while keeping onclick functionality in tact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.preloader').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I just edited my post... while keeping onclick functionality in tact?

Comment: even shorter `$('.preloader').click();`

Comment: @santa. all you need is to add that line. keep your other code.

Answer (score 1):

you don't even need to modify it as long as you still want the function to get called when the link is clicked.

you should be able to just add this to your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.preloader').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this solve your issue?

```
$(function () {
    $.loader({ className:"ajLoad", content:"" });
    // the rest of your JS here
});
```

Comment: The loader icon comes on but never goes away... sorry.